# adb command list to perform different functions

Tags: android, adb

I have been exploring various options with adb by connecting to real device. Went thru the android documents.

By reading random documents, i found out that i can open a webpage directly by adb using

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://www.wikipedia.org
```

or i can send BT turn On request using

```
adb shell am start -a android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE
```

I am wondering, if i can find all such functions at one place or how to explore more about what all could be done using adb.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://codeadapter.blogspot.in/) is a collection of ***ADB commands*** , i am collected from various sites & books

Please go through this . Feel free to ask any doubts regarding these commands

Comment: Thanks, but as i gave example of BT on. I am looking for examples like wifi ON or change some settings or send sms etc via adb.

Comment: Ok.I am working on it.Once i complete i will inform you.